# Best way to browse Powershell help?

Tags: powershell, documentation

I'm a Powershell user. I think the Get-Help is useful, but I don't like to read help in the console. Is there a program that can display the help in an external window? with links and display that you would expect from a help system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://powershelltools.com works great for this...

Answer (score 2):

[Windows PowerShell 2.0 help in graphical help format (.chm file).](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=FEFB2572-559A-46FE-978D-5A00490B20FA&displaylang=en)

"View the Windows PowerShell 2.0 help (including cmdlet help and the About topics) in a fully-searchable, graphical format (a standard Windows .chm file). Also included in the help file is the VBScript to Windows PowerShell Conversion Guide and a collection of PowerShell Tips of the Week."